# How to pass multiple json value for post method using fiddler

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I'm new with web api and fiddler as well as json, i want to test my api with fiddler.
In this image i've recieved the requested data
[image: In this image i've recieved the requested data]

and I've returned Json data to mobile device but now when i want to test it through fiddler web debugger

[image: fiddler]

it shows "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" in fiddler Headers tab

Comment: Which fiddler are you using? If it's of browser, please specify browser name.

Comment: I'm using "Fiddler Web Debugger" free tool @Dhwani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a method that takes as a parameter the object sent as JSON. WebApi will handle the deserialization for you.

Something like this on server side would work:

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]Book book)
    {
        // do someting with book here...
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public string OfficeCode { get; set; }
    public string BookNo { get; set; }
    public string MeterNo { get; set; }
    public string AccountNo { get; set; }
}
```

From the client, the body should look like

```
{
   "OfficeCode": "string",
   "BookNo": "string",
   "MeterNo": "string",
   "AccountNo": "string"
}
```

Comment: Yes, i got it. But i don't want to make another class, i want to test those data as value type not as object type. Now, how can i do that with fiddler web debugger tool?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting method name.

Give full URL as below:

`http://localhost:9090/api/ReadingBook/PostCustomerBills`

Also I can see that you haven't specified `[HttpPost]` on `PostCustomerBills` method.

Comment: I've tried in this way, but it doesn't work... still get 500 internal server error